# Firestore issue Saveall method

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to implement a code on Sringboot and firestore but when i'm trying to save more than 15000 document there is an issue, can you hlep me?, this is my code:

```
Flux<MyDocument> users = Flux.fromIterable(result);
firestoreTemplate.saveAll(users).blockLast();
```

if result is a list of more than 15000 record (aprox) there is an issue.

Regards.

Comment: Hi Diego, just a suggestion, please also post the details of the issue/error you are seeing. It will help members to identify the exact issue and suggest you solutions..

Comment: what the really issue is

Comment: Hi @diegocontreras please, add more information and details to your questions, so it's possible to either reproduce or have a better understanding for your case. As indicated in this article [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), more information is needed. Add details such as more parts of your code related to uploading the data, the stack trace that you mentioned to be an "issue" when it's more than 15000, etc. With this information, it might be possible to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore must be in "Datastorage" mode to remove the insert restriction:
[image]